# ORDER BY ... COLLATE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, collation, case-sensitive

Under SQL Server. A table contains some text with different cases. I want to sort them case-sensitive and thought that a `COLLATE` in the `ORDER BY` would do it. It doesn't. Why?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (C1 VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO T1 (C1) VALUES ('aaa1'), ('AAB2'), ('aba3')

SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY C1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY C1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Both queries return the same, even if the first one is "CS" for case-sensitive

```
aaa1
AAB2
aba3
```

(in the first case, I want `AAB2, aaa1, aba3`)

My server is a SQL Server Express 2008 (10.0.5500) and its default server collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

The collation of the database is `Latin1_General_CI_AS` too.

The result remains the same if I use `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` in place of `Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that **is** the correct case sensitive collation sort order. It is explained in [Case Sensitive Collation Sort Order](http://rusanu.com/2012/11/23/case-sensitive-collation-sort-order/) why this is the case, it has to do with the [Unicode specifications for sorting](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/). `aa` will sort ahead of `AA` but `AA` will sort ahead of `ab`.

Answer (score 14):

You need a binary collation for your desired sort order with `A-Z` sorted before `a-z`.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY C1 COLLATE Latin1_General_bin
```

The CS collation sorts `aAbB ... zZ`