# Order By clause not sorting properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is one of the most interesting issue that I have come across in quiet some time. I have a scalar function defined in SQL server 2008 which whose return type is `varchar(max)`

This is the query:

```
 Select dbo.GetJurisdictionsSubscribed(u.UserID) as 'Jurisdiction' From Users u ORDER BY Jurisdiction desc
```

Could anybody explain why would `AAAA...` 2nd record in the resultset? I am doing a descending sort, `AAA...` should appear at the last. If I change the query to

```
Jurisdiction asc
```

`AAA` goes 2nd last in the list instead of the 1st record.

This is the screenshot of the resultset: http://i48.tinypic.com/23j5vzq.jpg

Am I missing something?

Comment: Two collation questions within a 20 minutes? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13822220/105929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, as you can see in your screenshot, they are a white space in other rows before 'Wise' word (and withe space is greater than 'A')

You can [left trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) this spaces with:

```
ORDER BY ltrim( Jurisdiction ) desc
```

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct sort order. You have spaces. You must read [Case Sensitive Collation Order](http://rusanu.com/2012/11/23/case-sensitive-collation-sort-order/).

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why couldn't I see the space! I wasted nearly 1/2 hr and still couldn't make out that there was space :)

Answer (score 0):

notice the leading white spaces, try

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY LTRIM(Jurisdiction) desc
```

`LTRIM` would be fine.

Comment: Is there a Trim function? I guess you meant LTrim(RTrim())

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell on the screenshot, but can you check the length of the values because I think some of them have a leading space. If so then they would be sorted correctly.