# How does sql server order by work with pipe character

Tags: sql, sql-server

It appears that SQL server must do something special when ordering by character columns that contain pipe characters.

ascii('|') returns 124 as does unicode('|')

ascii('0') returns 48

Order by returns '|' character before letters and numbers.

I have tried to look at collations and in the cases I have looked at, the '|' character always has value 124.

Here is my test select

```
select * from (
   select '0' as col1, ASCII('0') as col2, unicode('0') as col3
   union select '1' as col1, ASCII('1') as col2, unicode('1') as col3
   union select '|' as col1, ASCII('|') as col2, unicode('|') as col3
   union select 'a' as col1, ASCII('a') as col2, unicode('a') as col3
   union select ' ' as col1, ASCII(' ') as col2, unicode(' ') as col3
   union select '.' as col1, ASCII('.') as col2, unicode('.') as col3
   union select '/' as col1, ASCII('/') as col2, unicode('/') as col3

) as q
order by col1
```

This query returns:

```
    col1  col2  col3
1           32    32
2      .    46    46
3      /    47    47
4      |   124   124
5      0    48    48
6      1    49    49
7      a    97    97
```

Why does 124 fall between 47 and 48?

The collation being used is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI.

If only binary collations use the ascii/unicode value of the characters for sorting, how can I find what the sort ordering is for characters in this collation?

Comment: It is only binary collations that use the character codes for sorting. `SELECT ASCII('A'), ASCII('a')` returns `65,97` but in most collations these sort next to each other.

Comment: My instance is using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI so you are correct 'A' and 'a' sort next to each other.  Do you know how to find the sort ordering for that collation?

Comment: It's not that simple. `SELECT CHAR(number) FROM master..spt_values WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 255 ORDER BY CHAR(number)` gives some idea. But then if you look at the sort order for `SELECT 'Æ' AS X UNION SELECT 'AE' UNION SELECT 'AF' ORDER BY X` this isn't per the single character sort order.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, if you put that into an answer I'll accept it.  Between printing out the values using your query and the unicode spec, http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/,  found in the accepted answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822220/order-by-collate-in-sql-server I think I get it now.

Comment: TBH I'm not at all au fait  with all the gory details of sorting in SQL Server, if you've researched it more extensively then post the results of your research.

Answer (score 3):

Different collations change the comparison order of characters. They do *not* change the ASCII code or Unicode value of any characters. In other words, collations are almost never simply ordering by ASCII code or Unicode value.

Comment: Do you know how to tell what the value of a character is in a particular collation?

Comment: @G_A - You mean `SELECT ASCII(CAST(N'ф' COLLATE Bosnian_Cyrillic_100_CS_AS AS CHAR(1)))`? Or something else?

Comment: @MartinSmith If that is the value that order by will use for comparisons then yes.  SELECT ASCII(CAST(N'|' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI AS CHAR(1))) 
 returns 124 just as ascii('|') and unicode('|') functions.

Comment: @G_A - No it isn't the value used for sorting. Except in binary collations.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments and answers mentioned, the order by order is determined by the collation.  The position of the character in the unicode charts does factor into the order.

From the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)  The collation sequence is based on a multi level comparison algorithm consisting of:

```
Base Characters
Accents
Case Variants
Punctuation
Identical Level
```

Where the Identical Level is some rule for how to break ties when two strings are identical.

More than the rules of how this works, I wanted to find what that ordering would be for a given collation.  I have not been able find any documentation on what is the ordering of characters would be for a given collation, but it can be displayed using a query.

```
SELECT CHAR(number) 
FROM master..spt_values 
WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 255 
ORDER BY CHAR(number) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
```