# How to display drop down options alphabetically without worrying about case sensitive in classic asp?

Tags: sorting, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a drop down box in my classic ASP page and using MS SQL for database. The drop down list includes the brand names starting with lower case, upper case and starting brand name with numbers.

For instance, `itcosmetics`, `Colorpop Cosmetics` and `5 Hour energy` respectively. Currently, this dropdown is showing/displaying brands alphabetically but by case i.e. lower case, number, upper case.

In other words, it is displaying all lower case brand name alphabetically first then the brand with numbers alphabetically and finally brand names starting with uppercase alphabetically.

However, what I am trying is : I want to display my options according to the alphabetical orders without worrying about the case of the brand name.

for example: if the brand names are `1 apple`, `applea`, `Appleb`, `3 fans`, `balla`, `Ballb`, `cat`, `Doll`.

Currently, its displaying drop down option as following:

```
applea
balla
cat
1 apple
3 fans
Appleb
Ballb
Doll
```

But I want something like following:

```
1 apple
3 fans
applea
Appleb
balla
Ballb
cat
Doll
```

How can I do that?

My code :

```
<select>
    <OPTION value=0>-- SELECT --</OPTION>
        <% 
            DIM RS, varQueryBrand, varBrand

            IF Request.QueryString("brandID") <> "" THEN
                varQueryBrand = Request.QueryString("brandID")
            ELSE
                    varQueryBrand = "SELECT"
            End IF

            SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(brand) as brand FROM tblproduct"

            SET RS=objConn.Execute(SQL)  

            IF NOT (RS.BOF and RS.EOF) THEN 
                WHILE NOT RS.EOF
                    varBrand = RS("brand") 
                    IF LCase(varQueryBrand) = LCase(varBrand) THEN
                        Response.Write "<option selected value=""" & replace(RS("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & RS("brand") & "</option>"
                    ELSE            
                        Response.Write "<option value=""" & replace(RS("brand")," & ","@") & """>" & RS("brand") & "</option>"
                    End IF
                    RS.MoveNext
                WEND 
            END IF
                 RS.close
                SET RS = nothing
        %>
    </select>
```

I tried writing `ORDER BY brand` at the end of SQL statement, but there was no chage in the output. So can you please help me?

Comment: What about `ORDER BY LOWER(brand) ASC`? It's not ideal though I'd probably wrap it in a sub query pull out the `LOWER(brand) [brand_low]` then `ORDER BY [brand_low]` outside of the sub query.

Comment: This might help you understand better - [ORDER BY … COLLATE in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822220/order-by-collate-in-sql-server), suggestion to use a binary collation might be what you are after - `ORDER BY brand COLLATE Latin1_General_bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using a Collation with the `CS` designation in it like `Latin1_General_CS_AS` for example.

To avoid the Unicode Sorting, switch to a Binary Collation to get the expected sort order.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT brand 
FROM tblproduct 
ORDER BY brand COLLATE Latin1_General_bin
```

A slightly messier approach is to use a sub query to wrap a lowercase version of the `Brand` column and use that for sorting.

```sql
SELECT x.brand
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT brand, LOWER(brand) [brand_lower]
  FROM tblproduct
) x
ORDER BY x.brand_lower
```

As [@Martha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121333/martha) [point's out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848722/692942) don't forget to specify an `ORDER BY` in your SQL string in Classic ASP.

---

#### Useful Links

- [ORDER BY … COLLATE in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13822298/692942)

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you aren't currently sorting your results at all, so you're getting whatever default order SQL Server cares to come up with.

Most databases are automatically set to case-insensitive sorting, so unless your database is set up strangely, the following should work:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM tblproduct ORDER BY brand"
```

If that doesn't work and you don't feel like messing around with the COLLATION settings, you can sort by an all-lowercase (or all-uppercase) version of the field:

```
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM tblproduct ORDER BY LOWER(brand)"
```

Comment: When I tried 1st option you mentioned above, it did nothing. i.e. no change in my output. And for second option, it hide my all dropdown options other than "SELECT" default option. Also I am looking for mixed cases not only lower case 1st and upper case separately.

Comment: @VicStat: can you try running this query in the database manager itself (Enterprise Manager or SQL Server Management Studio or whatever it's called for your version of SQL Server)? Returning no results means that there's some sort of error happening.