Why the ORDER BY clause works like this?
I need help to find out why this behaviour (not a solution). It's about the ORDER BY clause in SQL Server. It has nothing to do with the related post, because my case it's not about case sensitive/insensitive.
Here's the code.
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A = '-' UNION select '/' 
UNION 
SELECT '-A'  UNION select '/A' 
) B
ORDER BY A

Why do I get this result?
-
/
/A
-A


It's due to collation rules. Try SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 ORDER BY COLOR COLLATE Latin1_General_bin

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822220/order-by-collate-in-sql-server

Thanks for the reply, Mitch. It works with COLLATE Latin1_General_bin. But with COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI doesn't.

Actually it "works" with either. In both cases it returns the data in the order as defined by the collation. The confusion is in what you are expecting as results. This behavior is well documented.
